# Account permissions on Windows 7 to allow easy access for one account, restricted for another

Tags: windows-7, permissions

I have three accounts on my PC:

- Administrator
- Account_1 (Limited)
- Account_2 (Limited)

What I want is to prevent Account_2 from accessing cmd.exe and taskmgr and permit Account_1 to access it easily.

I tried Windows 7's security options, but I was unable to add Account_2 to the list and deny the Read, Write & Execute access.

Comment: What version of Win7? Professional and Ultimate give you access to Group Policies, which are designed for this sort of thing.

Comment: Ultimate. Group policies will disable the app for all users even the administrator :S

Answer (score 1):

Try AppLocker.  A bit of a sledge hammer for this task but you can easily use it to scope to a user or group of users.

[What Is AppLocker? Technet document](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723689%28WS.10%29.aspx)